# Убивает мгновенно врага

Tags: c#, unity3d

В IEnumerator"е я написал метод перехода анимации удара главного персонажа. Врагу наносится урон тогда, когда враг попадает в трехметровый луч от персонажа и когда проигрывается анимация удара(триггеров не использую). Дело в том, что анимация как и должна работает с перерывами(Она получилась автоматическая при попадании врага в луч). Но метод, который отнимает хп у врага, странно работает. Я задал, чтобы он отнимал по 10 хп при каждом проигрыше анимации. Но врага, у которого 100 хп он убивает меньше чем за секунду, словно этот метод работает в методе Update.

```
Скрипт игрока:

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    float maxhp = 100;
    public float curHp;
    Animator swordAnim;
    EnemyStates state;
    RaycastHit hit;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        curHp = maxhp;
        swordAnim = GameObject.FindWithTag("Sword").GetComponent<Animator>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 3f, Color.green);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 3))
        {            
                stGive();
                state = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyStates>();
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);            
        }

    }

    public void stGive()
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == ("Enemy"))
            StartCoroutine(GiveAt());
    }


      IEnumerator  GiveAt()
    {
        swordAnim.SetBool("attack", true);       
        swordAnim.SetBool("idle", false);
        state.GetDamage(10f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        swordAnim.SetBool("idle", true);
        swordAnim.SetBool("attack", false);

    }

}
```

скрипт врага :

```
public class EnemyStates : MonoBehaviour {

    float EnemyLife = 100;
    public float curEnemyLife;
    float damage;



    void Start () {

        curEnemyLife = EnemyLife;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(curEnemyLife <=0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }

    public void GetDamage(float dmg)
    {        
        curEnemyLife -= dmg;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и есть(получилось как в update). У тебя в Update кидается raycast, потом проверяется stGive() на тэг, и запускается корутина. Так вот у тебя этих корутин запускается каждый кадр, в котором срабатывает проверка на тэг(то есть допустим за 1 секунду 60 кадров, 50 их них райкаст попадает и тэг подходит, запускается 50 корутин). За первые 10 корутин твой враг умирает(а это меньше секунды).

p.s. Учи мать часть по поводу корутин. Каждый запуск создает, независимый от предыдущего, объект.

Comment: Получается, что новая корутина может запуститься еще до завершения прошлой?

Comment: Может быть нужно в корутине флаг сделать? В самом начале корутины и конце